# Can share files be writable?

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, samba

I've tried many variations of code to allow files in a shared Windows folder to be writable. Initial code in a freshly made VM was based on [this tutorial](https://linuxsimply.com/ubuntu-samba-client/).
This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889784/unable-to-create-writable-share-in-samba) has an accepted answer on which I've based the code appearing below. My attempts to replicate the positive result of that post have failed.

My goal is to share the source code of a website in my home (i.e., not accessible in the wild) network just to see if it can be done. The source code is for a Symfony application, which requires the usual permissions of a website plus 777 for the `var` subfolder with its logs and caches. I added an empty file named `xyz` to test for writable.

The environment: Windows 10 Pro, version 22H2; VirtualBox v7 VM with Ubuntu Server 22.04.3.
Share is `\\geolaptop\diet`. VM is updated & upgraded. VM user is `sam` for ease of use. Below is the (best reconstruction of) sequence of commands I've used.

What needs to be changed to make the share writable?

code sequence:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils
sudo apt install samba
mkdir /home/sam/diet
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

   [diet]
       comment = Can sam work here?
       path = /home/sam/diet
       read only = no
       browsable = yes
       
sudo service smbd restart
sudo ufw allow samba
sudo smbpasswd -a sam
sudo smbpasswd -e sam
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

   [diet]
       comment = Can sam work here?
       path = /home/sam/diet
       read only = no
       browsable = yes
       force user = sam
       
sudo service smbd restart
cd ./diet
nano xyz  => not writable
       
sudo chmod -R 777 .
nano xyz  => not writable

sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
#map to guest = bad user
sudo service smbd restart
nano xyz  => not writable

sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

[diet]
   comment = Can sam work here?
   path = /home/sam/diet
   read only = no
   available = yes
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = no
   public = yes
   printable = no
   locking = no
   strict locking = no
   
sudo service smbd restart
nano xyz  => not writable

sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

[diet]
   comment = Can sam work here?
   path = /home/sam/diet
   read only = no
   available = yes
   browseable = yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = no
   public = yes
   printable = no
   locking = no
   strict locking = no
   force create mode = 0660
   force directory mode = 2770
   force user = sam
   force group = sam

sudo service smbd restart
nano xyz  => not writable
```